# Auto refresh Excel cell value/formula

Tags: excel

I currently have a very simple worksheet set up with a barcode scanner, in which the user scans his/her barcode to "clock in" and "clock out" with a running "elapsed duration" timer (I used the '=now() - clock in' row formula).

My problem is, the value in the "elapsed duration" cells do not automatically refresh and I have to manually click it and resubmit the formula to get the updated elapsed time. Is there a way I can automate this?

Attached screenshots for details.

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeltT.png

Comment: You don't have to actually resubmit the formula. ANY change on the worksheet will recalculate it. Just clicking in and out of ANY cell will recalculate it. Clicking on F9 will do the same.

Comment: @NiteshHalai thanks for your comment, I just tried it and while that seems like a reasonable solution, its not exactly ideal for the operation I'm running :/ is there any function to intermittently refresh it?

Comment: Are you open to using a macro?

Comment: @NiteshHalai yes, however I have no experience in VBA

Comment: I actually got a code for refreshing, but I have no idea on how to stop running it  without closing all the open workbooks. (I have very limited knowledge of VBA myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal could be achived by 2 simple VBA fucntions. One has to be attached to Workbook.Open event, second to newly added module.

Here is code from Open event (Alt+F11, Open ThisWorkbook code and paste the code):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"

End Sub
```

Second in new module (right click on Microsoft Excel Objects, choose Insert->Module and paste there code):

```
Public Sub EventMacro()
Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("L:L")
    rng.Calculate
    ' Here refresh interval can be changed
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```

TimeValue("00:02:00") defines intervals between refreshing, Range("L:L") defines columns to be refreshed.

EDIT:
Of course workbook has to saved as .xlsm to enable VBA codes.